# How to run two instances of tomcat on windows using two separate ports

Tags: java, tomcat7

I wanted to run two instances of the apache tomcat 7.0.x on the same windows machine but using port 8080 (one tomcat instance) on 8090 (another tomcat instance).

When I am trying to run the both instances at the same time using two different ports using windows CMD gives me following error. Please let me know what's wrong is happening.

```
    [![Several ports (8005, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are 
already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a 
system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop 
the other process or change the port number(s).][1]][1]
```

The screen shot for reference:-
[image]

Comment: Learn how to edit Server.xml

Comment: Check [this](http://www.ansoncheunghk.info/article/5-steps-install-multiple-apache-tomcat-instance-windows) one.

Comment: Have you read the error message? It's quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Eclipse. Double click on the `server` in `servers` tab. And Edit these three port and make sure for two servers these ports are different.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A default configured tomcat uses 3 ports 8080, 8009 and 8005. So if you want to start another tomcat server on same machine you will have to edit your server.xml likewise of that tomcat and change these port values to say for example 8090, 8019 and 8015. Only changing 8080 to 8090 wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Modify below ports to some other values in  server.xml which you can find in  {Tomcat installation folder}\conf.

1. Connector Port: 8080 (Default)
2. Shutdown Port: 8005 (Default) AJP
3. Port: 8009 (Default)
4. Redirect Port: 8100 (Default)

Please use this [link](http://www.ansoncheunghk.info/article/5-steps-install-multiple-apache-tomcat-instance-windows) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

One more aspect:

Depending on your setup you could

- disable (comment out) ajp13 port (8009 default)
- disable shutdown port (set to -1)

Which would in fact reduce your server.xml to one port to change.